# MongoDB Aggregate framework Error

Tags: mongodb, shell, aggregation-framework

i have a collection with this structure:

```
{ "_id" : "01002", "city" : "CUSHMAN", "loc" : [ -72.51564999999999, 42.377017 ], "pop" : 36963, "state" : "MA" }
```

i want to use  Aggregate framework to perform this query:

```
db.US.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"state":"$state"}}, sum:{$sum:"$pop"}}])
```

I"m getting this error:
**"Command 'aggregate' failed: exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field. (response: { "errmsg" : "exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.", "code" : 16435, "ok" : 0.0 })"**

way i get this error,it looks like a very simple one
 can anybody help
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep your brackets were a little out of whack.

```
db.US.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"state":"$state"}}, sum:{$sum:"$pop"}}])
```

change to:

```
db.US.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"state":"$state"}, sum:{$sum:"$pop"}}}])
```

Edit: actually this is better:

```
db.US.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:"$state", sum:{$sum:"$pop"}}}
])
```

since it results in a flat document instead of an array of ids:

```
{ "_id" : "MA", "sum" : 36963 }
```